# How to generate given number of random objects with given number of attributes?

Tags: java, object, random, enums

My question is, how to generate a random challenge with a given number (4 - 8) of trials?

A challenge is built from trials (see in code, below).

The trials are the attributes of the `Challenge` class, built from an enum and an [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html).

So when I get a random number in main (like `r.nextInt(4) + 4;`) I will generate that number of trials for a challenge as follows

```
Weapons = 25;
Hacking = 32;
Vehicle = 34;
Speed = 56;
```

So for 1 Challenge, I don't need all the trials, just some of them. But I still need the possibility to choose from them randomly (4 - 8).

How can I generate these random `Challenge` objects with given number of attributes (and the values of them)? So basically some of them, from ALL of them.

Is this all wrong? How should I start it?

The code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Challenge {
    Random r = new Random();

    // DRIVE, VEHICLE, ACCURACY, WEAPONS, REFLEX, STRATEGY, CHARISMA, HACKING,
    // SPEED, STEALTH;
    public static enum Trial {
        DRIVE, VEHICLE, ACCURACY, WEAPONS, REFLEX, STRATEGY, CHARISMA, HACKING, SPEED, STEALTH;
    }

    Map<Trial, Integer> challenge = new EnumMap<Trial, Integer>(Trial.class);

    public Challenge() {
        challenge.put(Trial.DRIVE, r.nextInt(100) + 25);
        challenge.put(Trial.VEHICLE, r.nextInt(100) + 25);
        challenge.put(Trial.ACCURACY, r.nextInt(100) + 25);
        challenge.put(Trial.WEAPONS, r.nextInt(100) + 25);
        challenge.put(Trial.REFLEX, r.nextInt(100) + 25);
        challenge.put(Trial.STRATEGY, r.nextInt(100) + 25);
        challenge.put(Trial.CHARISMA, r.nextInt(100) + 25);
        challenge.put(Trial.HACKING, r.nextInt(100) + 25);
        challenge.put(Trial.SPEED, r.nextInt(100) + 25);
        challenge.put(Trial.STEALTH, r.nextInt(100) + 25);
    }

    List<Trial> keys = new ArrayList<Trial>(challenge.keySet());
    Trial randomKey = keys.get(r.nextInt(keys.size()));
    Integer value = challenge.get(randomKey);
}
```

Comment: Hint: please read that information around that edit window. We use markdown language here not `<br>` tags ;-)

Comment: Thanks! 
I tried to figure out how to make it but i gave up. Will care next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, you want to generate a challenges with `t` trials, where `int t = random.nextInt(5) + 4`, such that `4 <= t <= 8` (note that [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-)'s bound is *exclusive*). Every trial gets an associated value of `random.nextInt(100) + 25` (so between 25 and 124), if I read your code correctly.

You can do so as follows. We create an array with all trials and randomly select `t` out of them by shuffling the array and taking the first `t`. We put those in the map, with an associated value.

```
Map<Trial, Integer> challenge = new EnumMap<Trial, Integer>(Trial.class);
int t = 4 + random.nextInt(5);
// collect all Trial values in a list
List<Trial> allTrials = Arrays.asList(Trial.values());
// shuffle that list
Collections.shuffle(allTrials);
// select the number of trials we want, add them to challenge
for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
  challenge.put(allTrials.get(i), random.nextInt(100) + 25);
}

// example output: {DRIVE=121, WEAPONS=119, STRATEGY=59, HACKING=78, STEALTH=72}
System.out.println(challenge);
```

Comment: Thank you! And how Can I add the name of the trial ?

Comment: @Viktor Add to where?

Comment: Nope, just misunderstanding. But eclipse gives me this 
Syntax error on tokens, SimpleName expected instead
This happens at the shuffleing method

Comment: It works on my machine. You might want to Google that and if you cannot solve it, ask a separate question.

Comment: I get back Challenge@515f550a this memory address when printing out. Why is that ?

Comment: Sounds like you are printing the Challenge class instance instead of the EnumMap.

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question correctly, you are asking: how to pick one of those enums in a random fashion?

If so; you can use `values()` to put all enum constants into an array; to then simply select a random entry in that array. Alternatively, you can simply shuffle that array; and always return the first element.

```
Trial allTrials[] = Trial.values();
Random random = new Random();

Trial pickRandomTrial() {
  return allTrials[random.nextInt(allTrials.length)];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 
And how Can I add the name of the trial ?

Comment: You want to do some more reading on enums. They have methods to acquire such information. Seriously: study the concepts you intend to use before using them :-)

Answer (score 0):

> But I still need the possibility to choos from them randomly(4-8).

you can use

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int min = 4;
    int max = 8;

    System.out.println(r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min);
```